# avoid /map topic replacement

Tags: navigation, rviz, ros-melodic, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.
I have been mapping an environment using **Rviz** and **gmapping**  with Gazebo as simulator and saved the map in a folder.
Now I want to load it back, so I run `rosrun map_server map_server mymap.yaml`, then I launch (in order) Gazebo and Rviz. If I don't launch **gmapping**, Rviz notifies me with an error, which is understandable, that says "Missing transform between /map and /odom". That is telling me that I didn't provide it (through **gmapping**, because in this case I haven't launched it).
The problem is that, if I do launch gmapping, the map gets updated with the new laserscan readings and I lose the previously-uploaded map.

How can I do in order to

- Have the transform /map -> /odom
- Render the map in Rviz correctely
- Avoid /map updates through **gmapping**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335395/avoid-/map-topic-replacement/) by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you already have a map you don't need to use gmapping anymore. Gmapping is used for localization **and** mapping. You need to use the package [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) that creates the transform `map -> odom`, it's only responsible for the localization of the robot.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-10-15**:
I already know the spawn position of my robot, therefore amcl will just guess where the robot is, without any reason to

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-15**:\

> amcl will just guess where the robot is

It will not just localize the robot but it will also publish the transform `odom -> map` that you need. Have you tried it ?

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-10-15**:
I did, but while the transformation ends up correctly mapping the uploaded map in respect with the odometry, the position of the robot isn't mapped even after multiple iterations, resulting in no collisions whatsoever.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-15**:\

> the position of the robot isn't mapped even after multiple iterations

Can you elaborate this ? If there is an "offset" when launching `amcl` whith the initial pose in amcl node and the initial pose of Gazebo then after moving the robot it should be corrected. If you don't move the robot then this offset won't be corrected. Is that what you meant ?

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-10-15**:
Yes, there is an offset between the two positions that won't be corrected even after moving the robot

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-15**:
You need to specify the same initial pose to the `AMCL` node and to the `spawn_model` node.

But maybe it's something else in the configuration : have you changed some frames/topics names ? If some like `scan`, `odom` or `map` don't have the default value you need to specify it to the `AMCL` node.

Finally, there are the parameters `update_min_d` and `update_min_a` that by default are at the value `0.2` and `pi/6` meaning that the position won't be refreshed if the robot haven't moved by more than `20cm` or rotated by more than `pi/6` rad. So when you said you moved the robot, did you moved it more than those two values (or just one at least) ?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-15**:
Have a look at the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) to see all the parameters

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-10-15**:
Ok now it works! There's still a little bit of bias between the collision perceptions and the loaded map (some walls get hit slightly before than what's rendered) but I can take it. Thanks!